# stat st_mode is always equal to 16877

Tags: c, unix, system-calls, stat

I want to know if a file is a directory or a regular file with stat :

```
#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int is_regular_file(const char *path)
{
    struct stat path_stat;
    stat(path, &path_stat);
    return S_ISREG(path_stat.st_mode);
}
```

I try on Mac and Linux and when I print S_ISREG(path_stat.st_mode) is always equal to 1 and path_stat.st_mode is always equal to 16877.

Comment: when the returned value is `1` then it is a regular file.  The value `16877` is the combination of the file permission bits and the file mode bits (and a few other things.)  I.E. it is a bit map and the macro `S_ISREG` is simply extracting a single bit from that stat field.  Suggest reading the `man` file for `stat`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`16877` is octal `40755`, which denotes a directory (octal `40000`) with permissions `755` (user has full rights, everyone else has read and traversal rights).  As suggested, the `stat` and `chmod` manual pages are useful.

Just for example, here is a screenshot with my [directory-editor](https://invisible-island.net/ded/ded.html) showing octal modes (an option) rather than the usual symbol ones:

[image: ded showing octal permissions]

Answer (score 3):

> `path_stat.st_mode` is always equal to `16877`

The value of `st_mode` has to be interpreted by bits:

The low 12 bits are the file access permissions that you can set with `chmod`. Each bit represents one file permission. The high 4 bits are the file type.

The low 12 bits of the 16-bit number `16877` would be `000111101101`. This combination means:

`---rwxr-xr-x` (read, write, execute for the owner of the file; read and execute for others). This combination is typical for directories and for executable files.

The high 4 bits of the number `16877` are 4 which (at least on Linux mean): "Directory".

> `S_ISREG(path_stat.st_mode)` is always equal to ...

The `S_ISREG` macro simply checks if the upper 4 bits of the argument have the value that means: "File type is a regular file."

> ... is always equal to 1

This confuses me a little: `16877` should be a directory; however `S_ISREG` should return 1 for regular files and 0 for anything else (such as directories).